# ffmpeg live stream transcoding. A/V sync issues on fast camera movement

Tags: go, ffmpeg, webrtc, http-live-streaming

1. I create a webrtc peer connection with my server(only stun)
2. Using [pion webrtc](https://github.com/pion/webrtc) for the server
3. I write the received RTP packets as VP8 and opus streams, [as described here](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/blob/master/examples/save-to-disk/main.go), to two pipes (the writers; created with os.Pipe() in golang)
4. The read ends of these two pipes are received by ffmpeg as inputs (via exec.Command.ExtraFiles) for transcoding using libx264 and aac into a single stream. The command:

```sh
ffmpeg -re -i pipe:3 -re -r pipe:4 -c:a aac -af aresample=48000 -c:v libx264 -x264-params keyint=48:min-keyint=24 -profile:v main -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 20 -fflags genpts -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -vsync vfr -map 0:0,0:0 -map 1:0,0:0 -f matroska -strict -2 pipe:5
```

5. The above command outputs to a pipe(:5) the read end of which is being taken as input by the following:

```sh
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -re -i pipe:3 -sn -vf scale=-1:'min(ih,360)' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -ca aac -b:a 128k -b:v 1400k -maxrate 1498k -bufsize 2100k -hls_time 1 -hls_playlist_type event -hls_base_url /workdir/streamID/360p -hls_segment_filename /workdir/streamID/360p/360_%%03d.ts -f hls /workdir/streamID/360p.m3u8
```

5. This works fine as long as there are no movements of my webcam. The moment that happens the video speed suddenly increases for a split second and audio delay gets introduced. This delay keeps increasing each time I shake my webcam.

The first command in point 4 above - if written to a file separately will be absolutely fine, in terms of a/v sync, even with vigorous camera shaking. The weird audio delay is only when transcoding for hls output irrespective of whether I'm actually viewing it live or playing it back later.

This is my first time working with ffmpeg/hls/webrtc - would be really helpful if I could be pointed in the correct direction at least to be able to debug this or even know why this happens. Any and all help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I think you can rule out step 1-4 as the issue, since the destination file has not issues. You can save it to disk and everything works great? Only when taking this file to HLS it has issues? I just want to rule out anything with WebRTC/first ffmpeg command.

Comment: My guess is that ffmpeg is trying to compensate for some kind of packet loss or frame rate changes? The camera movement is possibly causing the bitrate to spike/keyframes to be generated. If you instead take the video to another format (.mp4) instead of HLS does it cause you issues?

Comment: @SeanDuBois absolutely no issues if i convert to mp4

Comment: Interesting. If you then take that `mp4` to HLS does it still have issues? If you feel comfortable sharing the video file I would re-post your question just under the `ffmpeg` tag. I have a feeling a lot of people are going to ignore because they see WebRTC and Pion. But if you just say `x file breaks when I convert to HLS` I think you will get a lot more help :)

Comment: Also! It would be really awesome if you could contribute a simple `WebRTC -> HLS` to https://github.com/pion/example-webrtc-applications. No rush, but I could see this helping a lot of other people.

Comment: was able to get it to work by first creating a [webm out of it](https://github.com/pion/example-webrtc-applications/tree/master/save-to-webm). I am not very sure why this one works though - makes me believe ffmpeg has trouble with the way individual ivf or opus stream stores timecodes. will certainly send a pr for this.

Comment: I had same issue when waved my hand near webcam I got frozen and broken picture. I increased hls_time up to 4 (apple recommends set to 6 seconds), and video normalized, but I have latency about 6-8seconds. No ideas how to fix it for now. Perhaps this latency is normal in common ways for my project